# Validating all inputs field of only visible tabs of form

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Iam new to Javascript, I have a form divided in 8 tabs, 5 of wich are always visible and 3 only shows on certain conditions and 3 disable from which are visible. I have a save button and when the user clicks on it I need to validate the data in all visible form.
but only active tab fields are validate, then i use below script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script>

<script>
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        ignore: ""
    });
```

Now save button not submit untill all validations are correct its fine,NOW
 the problem is that its also validate the three tabs are hidden it's included in the validation process.

```
Now what i should do? only visible tabs are validate? HELP
```

here is my tabs

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs fixedWidth">

                                <li class="active">
                                    <a href="#tab_1_1" data-toggle="tab" id="ind">
                                        Customer Details for Individual
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#tab_1_2" data-toggle="tab" id="business">
                                        Customer Details for Business
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#tab_1_3" data-toggle="tab">
                                        Identification Information
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#tab_1_4" data-toggle="tab">
                                        Contact Details
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#tab_1_5" data-toggle="tab" id="ind1">
                                        Joint Applicant Details
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#tab_1_6" data-toggle="tab" id="ind2">
                                        Customer Due Diligence
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#tab_1_7" data-toggle="tab" id="business1">
                                        Customer Due Diligence (Business)
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#tab_1_8" data-toggle="tab">
                                        Other Informations
                                    </a>
                                </li>

                            </ul>
```

the script for hide and show is

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#INDUSTRY_ID').on('change', function () {
            if (this.value == '41') {
                $("#ind").show();
                $("#ind1").show();
                $("#ind2").show();
                document.getElementById("ind").click();


                $("#business").hide()
                $("#business1").hide();
            }
            else {

                $("#business").show();
                $("#business1").show();
                document.getElementById("business").click();
                $("#ind").hide();
                $("#ind1").hide();
                $("#ind2").hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

and the divs are

```
    <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="tab_1_1">
......
...
 <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab_1_2">
so on
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this...

```
     $.validator.setDefaults({ 
       ignore: [],
    // any other default options and/or rules
});
```

Comment: change ignore: "" to ignore: ":hidden"  .only active tab is validate, not validate all active and inactive tabs.

Comment: @@Umair Ikhtiar it will validate all the fields please try this

Comment: Now validate all fields also hide tabs field, i want only validate those tabs field which are show either active or inactive

Comment: what i understand from you question is when user clicks on that disable(i.e gives input that fields) then only that fields should get validate right?

Comment: there are 8 tabs, at a time 5 shows and 3 hide by jquery, i want ony those fields validate which are showing either on active tab or inactive tabs, if i chose another dropdown so those field are validate which tabs now showing

Comment: :disable also validate all tabs those are hide )-: